# Toggle Class for each div that reaches top of page

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find a way to adding and removing a class to a fixed element when each div containing the class, '.dark', reaches the top of the page.

I've got a working example here that works for the first instance of '.dark'.

https://jsfiddle.net/wLqkb5yc/

But I can't seem to get it working for the second instance of the class.

The code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var hieghtThreshold = $(".dark").offset().top;
var hieghtThreshold_end  = $(".dark").offset().top +$(".dark").height() - 25 ;
    $(window).scroll(function() {

            $('.dark').each(function() {

            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (scroll >= hieghtThreshold && scroll <=  hieghtThreshold_end ) {
                $('header').removeClass('active');
            }
            else {
                $('header').addClass('active');
            }

            });
    });
});
```

Can anyone identify what I'm missing here?

Comment: You are calculating your threshold values for the first .dark element only ...

Comment: Do you know how I would calculate other instances of .dark? Or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Well if those element positions never change, you could calculate them all upfront, and put them in an array, or store them as custom data on the elements in question themselves. But if something like an orientation change, window size, font size change or zoom changes any of those positions, you will of course have to re-calculate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be easier to find an element with the required coordinates.
We will search for the element that is located just below the logo.

```
var searchClass = 'dark';
var logoHeader = $('header');
var height = logoHeader.height();
$(window).scroll(function() {
        var elem = document.elementFromPoint(0,height);
        var eClass = $(elem).attr('class');
        classes = (eClass == undefined ? [] : eClass.split(' '));
        (classes.indexOf(searchClass) > -1 ? 
            logoHeader.addClass('active') :
            logoHeader.removeClass('active'));                  
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wLqkb5yc/7/

*PS. How to test? Here's the file, I added @media (max-width: 480px) to it, if the screen is less than 480px, then the header element will become 60px, the script will determine its height and also will correctly determine the coordinates.*
https://www.dropbox.com/s/k2s8hz65g7xzeck/dark.html?dl=0

Comment: Ah this looks a lot easier and is very close! Is there anyway to get it working with multiple classes? eg. class="bgWhite dark another-class"?

Comment: Ah damn - whilst this method works for desktop, on tablet and mobile the header element is expected to change so the coordinates are incorrect.

Comment: Coordinates can be worked separately for different forms factors

Comment: Nearly there I think! When you say form factors, do you mean like this?
 https://jsfiddle.net/wLqkb5yc/6/  - currently not working

Comment: You can determine the height at the start https://jsfiddle.net/wLqkb5yc/7/

Comment: Updated comment, attached test file

Comment: Your latest comment works perfectly! :-) Thank you for the help, sorry it took so long, I've been looking into the different elements so I'm learning from it as well :-)